# Filter Multiple Text Files

Tags: string, batch-file, text, filter

I'm trying to filter a group of text files.

I want to remove any line which doesn't have a specified string, and leave others untouched.

How can I do this?

I'm running Windows 7, with no specific language. I have little to no experience with anything of this nature. This is a task I'd like to repeat every once in a while, but it would just be personal.

Comment: Submit your tried code.

Comment: If this is a rule I have violated, I apologize. I don't have any tried code because I have no idea what I'm doing.

Comment: This is easy. Use [for](http://ss64.com/nt/for2.html), [find](http://ss64.com/nt/find.html) and [output redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html). There are many examples on the net and on stackoverflow.

Comment: Johnny, Even if you don't have code, you know a bunch of context you haven't shared. What platform are you on? What language are you working in? Is this a one-off task, where a quick shell script would work? Or is this something your need to put into production within a larger context?

Answer (score 0):

Add a `findstr` command in `for /f`'s set will find the STRING in *text.txt*.

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('findstr STRING text.txt') do (
    echo %%a>>text2.txt
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a simple task using `findstr.exe` in system32 directory of Windows.

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\findstr.exe /I /C:"string in lines to copy" "Text File With Path" >"New File With Lines Containing Searched String.txt"
```

For details on all options offered by `findstr` open a command prompt window and run there `findstr /?`. Read the help output into the command prompt window.

And read also Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx).